# angularjs end to end testing with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, karma-runner

Has anyone been able to get angular end to end testing with asp.net mvc4 and karma?

Everything works fine for me except for the end to end tests. The views behave correctly, the unit tests work fine, but the end to end tests seem to indicate that there are no elements in the DOM in Karma. I can't verify that since there doesn't seem to be anyway to examine the dom generated by Karma.

The reason why I want to use MVC4 is because I like the way authorization works in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, so I wont mark it as such, this is more of a work around.

I've decided to go with chutzpah in order to run the jasmine unit tests, and specflow.xunit for "e2e" testing. It works well in a .net environment and integration into teamcity seems straight forward.